# What is the opposite of this condition?

Tags: logic

Condition: $(A=1) \land (C>1) \land (B<6)$

Opposite Condition: $(A\ne 1) \lor (C\le 1) \lor (B\ge 6)$

Is that true?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: thax, i didn't learn math for long time  so sometimes forgot

Comment: I have edited the question to use standard mathematical notation. Please make sure it accurately reflects your intention. Note that $\lor$ means "or" and $\land$ means "and".

Comment: ok, thank buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right:
\begin{align*}
&&\lnot((A=1) \land (C>1) \land (B<6))\\
&\Longleftrightarrow&\lnot(A=1) \lor \lnot(C>1) \lor \lnot(B<6) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow&(A \ne 1) \lor (C\le 1) \lor (B \ge 6)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple example of [De Morgan laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step-by-step. For simplification, we assume the standard ordering of the Reals. If we want to really be rigorous, i.e., for a  general ordering relation, then $\nless$ is just the negation of $<$:

Let's use $\lnot$ for negation, and let's group the sentences in pairs; I think it will be easier/clearer:

Condition: $[(A=1) \land (C>1)] \land[ (B<6)]$ , so that we have two sentences; $P:=[(A=1)\land 
(C>1)]$ ; $Q:=[B<6]$ . Set the internal sentences to be $A,C $ respectively.

Opposite Condition for $P$: $\lnot(A \land C)$ is: $\lnot A \lor\lnot C$. Negation of conjunction distributes
as the disjunction of negations.

Let's apply $\lnot$ to $P$ first:

$\lnot P=\lnot [(A=1)\land(C>1)]=\lnot (A=1) \lor\lnot (C>1)\equiv(A\neq 1)\lor (C\nge 1)$.

Now, let's do $\lnot Q$. We have $\lnot[B<6]\equiv[B\nless6]$.

Putting it all together, we get: $(A \neq 1) \lor(C\leq 1)\lor(B\nless 6)$.